# UK tourist visa after US tourist visa refusal under 214 (b)

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-refusals

I am an Indian citizen studying in Germany for 2 years and I hold a German residence permit. Last month I applied for the US tourist visa which was rejected for not having sufficient ties with Germany. I failed to understand the reason for rejection as I am still a student and I am also working part-time here in Germany and I receive the scholarship from the state. However, I wasn't asked these questions during my US visa interview and the visa was refused citing "ties with the home country are not strong". I had every reason to come back to Germany and finish my studies.

Now, I want to apply for the UK visit visa to visit my friends in London for a weekend. I want to know if my previous US visa refusal would affect my chances of getting the visa to the UK.

I have travelled to Qatar, Tunisia and Thailand in past along with many countries in the Schengen region.

Does it make sense to apply for the UK visa now or should I wait for some time as my US visa was rejected last month and there aren't any significant changes in my circumstances?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit (reply to *user16259* comment): I got the generic refusal note from US consulate for section 214(b). The officer indeed said that my ties to Germany aren't strong. However, my question is related to UK visa now, what are my chances given the fact that I got my US visa refused recently?

Edit: Thanks everyone for commenting. It would be great if someone could answer my question regarding the UK visa application. Does it make sense to apply now and US visa refusal has no influence on my application or should I wait for sometime before applying until my circumstances change?

Comment: You're young, unattached, no job.  Your chances of a US tourist visa are about zero.

Comment: Can you post the refusal notice with personal info redacted? Perhaps they refer to India rather than Germany when saying your ties to your home country are not strong.

Comment: @LorenPechtel How is OP unattached when they're studying in Germany?

Comment: @user16259 It's the country of residence that should be considered.

Comment: You got a temp residence status as a student, that's why i guess they denied your application

Comment: @Crazydre Unattached as in unmarried/no kids.  If you look like someone who will use a tourist visa to illegally immigrate you're not going to get a US visa.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Damn good thing I'm a VWP national then xD I'm in my lower 20s, study in a foreign country and am as single as you can get.

Comment: @Crazydre Yeah, VWP countries have it much easier than visa-required countries.

Comment: I believe there are some situations where your US visa is rejected multiple times and as a consequence of that your UK visa gets rejected. A friend of mine got rejected for uk visa because he was rejected multiple times with uk visa.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I want to apply for the UK visit visa to visit my friends in London for a weekend.

Let know them about it definitely in the section for additional information.

You should have

1. Good savings, really good and evidence of that
2. Ask university for special reference where it is written that you are currently a full-time student. In my county each university can make such a reference, most probably your university does either.
3. In the invitation your friends will send to you make sure to note that they invited you for the exact period of time and after this period they are going to keep studying or working.

I do not think that US visa refusal can somehow impact on UK visa application as they are two different counties. I also do not see any reason not to apply for now.
Good luck!

Comment: I think your final statement may be incorrect. It's fairly common for visa forms to have a question like "Have you ever had a visa for any country refused?", with a space for details of the refusal, and I believe the UK form still does. The important thing would be to (truthfully) provide evidence within the application that the US refusal was unjustified.

Comment: @origimbo The only countries that seem to ask these questions are Australia, Canada, New Zealand and the UK. The only reason that they would need to do so is a lack of confidence in their own decision making.

Comment: @origimbo yes, you are right, I have to change the last point.

Comment: @greatone Well, the question is about applying for UK visas, so this point seems highly relevant. And, sorry, but your claim of a lack of confidence is silly. By that reasoning, the only reason we ask job applicants for letters of reference is that we're not confident in our own ability to select candidates.